# Amazon Advertising Curl PHP

Tags: php, php-curl, amazon-product-api

Amazon offer a scratchpad for the advertising API with code in PHP and curl. Unfortunately the PHP code uses fopen - which is no good on my hosting server, where remote url open is off.

I've got this far, with the fopen section commented out (that worked on my home server, so I know $headers array is fine! $payload is jSON

The error I get is "Curl error: 500 The request processing has failed due to some unknown error, exception or failure. Please retry again."

```
 $headers = $awsv4->getHeaders ();
$payload="{"
        ." \"Keywords\": \"".stripslashes($_POST['book'])."\","
        ." \"Resources\": ["
        ."  \"CustomerReviews.StarRating\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Large\","
        ."  \"Images.Primary.Small\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.ByLineInfo\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.ContentInfo\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.Classifications\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.ExternalIds\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.Features\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.ProductInfo\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.TechnicalInfo\","
        ."  \"ItemInfo.Title\","
        ."  \"Offers.Listings.Price\""
        ." ],"
        ." \"PartnerTag\": \"keepchickens-21\","
        ." \"PartnerType\": \"Associates\","
        ." \"Marketplace\": \"www.amazon.co.uk\""
        ."}";
    $headerString = "";
   
   
    foreach ( $headers as $key => $value ) {
        $headerString .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
        
    }
    $params = array (
            'http' => array (
                'header' => $headerString,
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $payload
            )
        );
    $stream = stream_context_create ( $params );
    /*

    
    $fp = @fopen ( 'https://'.$host.$uriPath, 'rb', false, $stream );

    if (! $fp) {
        throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
    }
    $response = @stream_get_contents ( $fp );
    if ($response === false) {
        throw new Exception('<p>Nothing found</p>');
    }
    */
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$host.$uriPath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    $response=curl_exec($ch);
     echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
     echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($response);
    $data=json_decode($response);
```

Any ideas what is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you output the content of $headers from Amazon's PHP example, the only parameter that's returned is the Authorization (not Host, Content-Type, etc).  Additionally, the $header output uses commas but Amazon's curl example does not => https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/quick-start/using-curl.html.  Once that was addressed, I no longer have a 500 error (but now have this 400 error =>).

*HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: Server Date: Sat, 09 Mar 2024 20:22:52 GMT Content-Type: text/html Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: keep-alive x-amz-rid: 6V3GN7J90XWPVRDQ47WC Vary: Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Mar 2024 10:23:39 GMT ETag: "209-6130f780cc984" Accept-Ranges: bytes Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload*

The biggest hurdle (for me) seems to be in formatting the headers and fields from the php example for fopen to curl (which I believe are causing the 400 error).  Here's what I've managed to get so far, so hopefully this at least helps get you past the 500 error.

```
$authorization = $awsv4->getHeaders ();
$authorization = str_replace (","," ", $authorization);
print_r ($authorization);

$amzdate =  gmdate ( "Ymd\THis\Z" );

$data_string = array(
    "Keywords" => "xxxx",
    "PartnerTag" => "xxxx",
    "PartnerType" => "Associates",
    "Marketplace" => "www.amazon.com"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$host.$uriPath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Host: webservices.amazon.com',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript',
    'Accept-Language: en-US',
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'X-Amz-Date: ' . $amzdate,
    'X-Amz-Target: com.amazon.paapi5.v1.ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.SearchItems',
    'Content-Encoding: amz-1.0',
    'Authorization: ' . $authorization,
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data_string));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$response=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```